# Grafana: Status History with fixed amount of boxes

Tags: grafana

I am trying to visualize the uptime of some nodes in Grafana 9.4.3. Let's say I have 5 nodes and I want to have the uptime of those nodes in my network over time, say the last 6 hours. If in a certain time interval a node was online, show a green box, if it was offline, show a red box. A data source would provide information about whether the nodes for a time interval (e.g. 1pm - 2 pm) was available (let's simplify it here to be a "yes" or "no" answer)

I need to use "Status History", where supposedly 6 boxes are displayed per row, and in total wed have 5 rows (one for each node).

Now, when trying to build the panel, I use test data from grafana to build the dashboard before linking it up with the actual data sources. Test data (Scenario: "Grafana Live", Channel: "random-2s-stream"). What I get is the boxes, but with a flexible width as more data is generated:

[image]

What I want and need is that a fixed set of boxes is shown - and these boxes have a fixed width and height, always. An example is shown in the documentation for Status History: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/v9.4/panels-visualizations/visualizations/status-history/

This is the "query":

[image]

Anyone can point me where this can be achieved?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Grafana Test Data. But if this is for demonstration purposes only, couldn't you you use some public data source, that supports Query options, like https://prometheus.demo.do.prometheus.io/ ?

Comment: No idea why it wouldn't work with the TestData, but with the Prometheus mock data it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Width and height of boxes calculated automatically based on number on samples and number of time series supplied to panel.

The easiest way to fix the width is to specify `Max data points` within Query options.
[image]

As for height - afaik, there is now way to limit number of results of query. So you'll need to guarantee that your query returns same number of time series by yourself.

Comment: I tried this option already, yet didn't get the desired result. Regardless what number I specify in the field "max data points", more boxes appear. Of course I saved, applied the settings and reloaded the page.